# Bash, classify output of a command

Tags: bash

How to classify output of a command, es whereis command, so to append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries?

es

```
$ whereis node
node: /usr/bin/node* /usr/include/node/ /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz
```

////////////////////////////////

To be clear, for example, the ls command has the option

```
    -F, --classify
           Append indicator (one of * / => @ |) to entries
```

I would like the same option for the other commands that generate as oputput a list of files/directories/links ... i guess you may to apply the pipe | to the command output ...

Comment: Huh, sorry but didn't understand the question. Could you make it more clear.

Comment: if you want to add a character after some files names in a file list, look at `sed` command; otherwise I didn't either understand the question

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what are you talking about.
Try to use this:

```
whereis node | xargs ls -dF 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: You'll want to add `-d` to the ls command so you don't list directory contents. +1 for not reinventing the wheel

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I was change my answer.

Comment: Yes, this solves my question, thank you @VitaliyKalyuzhnyak !